# how can we pass multiple parameter using action in redux

Tags: redux, action, dispatch

**i am trying to send current video object  and timeStam of current selected video to action using dispatch but it does not work ..**

```
onPause={(e)=>{dispatch(Pause(e.timeStamp,state.video))}}
```

but from this code of line it didn't work

Comment: Hi, can you share the reducer and Pause function? This line of code looks fine.

Comment: You should add the code of function which you are dispatching. So that community can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I sent data through dispatch in the form of object like this**

```
onPause={(e) => {
                    dispatch(Pause({pauseTime: pauseTime, selectedVideoID: ID}));
                }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).